# Building phone app from aosp

Tags: android, build, android-source

I'm trying to build just a phone app from aosp. I've configured my work dir as it was described in google's guide. Then i'm going to my work dir, execute `source build/envsetup.sh` and get the following:

```
including device/asus/grouper/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a/vendorsetup.sh
including device/moto/wingray/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/crespo/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/maguro/vendorsetup.sh
including device/ti/panda/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
```

Then i'm executing command `mmm packages/apps/Phone/` and something goes wrong, i get

```
make: Entering directory `/home/build/WORK_DIR'
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/javalib.jar', needed by `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.android.phone.common_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/home/build/WORK_DIR'
```

Can anyone explain me what should i do? Should i build the whole android project first, or is it a bug in makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building the entire source at first...After that whenever you make changes in the source code of any application(in your case Phone), you need to rebuild the entire code. The rebuild process will not take time as only the changes will be built into the system image..Use "make" instead of "mmm" . However don't  use "make clean" as it will erase your earlier build and start from scratch. So the outline is:

1. Execute "make" for building the first time
2. Make your changes in the application
3. Execute "make" once again

Answer (score 1):

Use "make snod" if you just want only one component that is built to be attached to the system.img